# asSingleEntity() Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have the code below, it currently accepts a users "message" and then stores and displays it. At the moment, it only displays one message, then asks the user to delete it before they can add a new message. I was wondering if this was caused by the asSingleEntity() and what I could use to change it to allow the user to leave as many messages as they'd like?

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreService;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceFactory;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query.FilterOperator;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query.SortDirection;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Text;

// The application design is that authenticated users have zero or one messages.
//
// This class is not thread safe because it is possible to create 2 messages for
// a single user under the right conditions.  Also, the static initialization
// code is not thread safe either.  These problems can be solved using transactions. 
//
// All application messages are placed under a single parent entity.
public class Message {

    private static final String parentKind = "messageParent";

    private static final String entityKind = "message";
    private static final String userIdPropertyName = "userId";
    private static final String nicknamePropertyName = "nickname";
    private static final String textPropertyName = "text";

    private static final String csrfTokenPropertyName = "csrfToken";

    private static Key parentKey = null;

    private static SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();

    // Check if message parent exists; if not, then create it.
    static {
        Query query = new Query(parentKind);
        DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
        Entity parent = datastore.prepare(query).asSingleEntity();
        if (parent == null || parent != null) {
            parent = new Entity(parentKind);
            datastore.put(parent);
        }
        parentKey = parent.getKey();
    }

    private Entity entity = null;

    private Message(Entity entity) {
        this.entity = entity;
    }

    public Long getID() {
        return (Long) entity.getKey().getId();
    }

    public String getText() {
        return ((Text) entity.getProperty(textPropertyName)).getValue();
    }

    public String getNickname() {
        return (String) entity.getProperty(nicknamePropertyName);
    }

    private void setNickname(String nickname) {
        entity.setProperty(nicknamePropertyName, nickname);
    }

    private void setText(String text) {
        entity.setProperty(textPropertyName, new Text(text));
    }

    public String getCsrfToken() {
        return (String) entity.getProperty(csrfTokenPropertyName);
    }

    private void save() {
        DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
        datastore.put(entity);      
    }

    public void delete() {
        DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
        datastore.delete(entity.getKey());  
    }

    public static Message createOrUpdate(String userId, String nickname, String text) {
        Message message = getByUserId(userId);
        if (message != null) {
            message.setNickname(nickname);
            message.setText(text);
        } else {
            Entity entity = new Entity(entityKind, parentKey);
            entity.setProperty(userIdPropertyName, userId);
            entity.setProperty(nicknamePropertyName, nickname);
            entity.setProperty(textPropertyName, new Text(text));
            entity.setProperty(csrfTokenPropertyName, "" + secureRandom.nextLong());
            message = new Message(entity);
        }
        message.save();
        return message;
    }

    public static List<Message> getAll() {
        Query query = new Query(entityKind, parentKey).addSort(nicknamePropertyName, SortDirection.ASCENDING);
        DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
        Iterator<Entity> entityIter = datastore.prepare(query).asIterator();
        List<Message> messageList = new LinkedList<Message>();
        while (entityIter.hasNext()) {
            messageList.add(new Message(entityIter.next()));
        }
        return messageList;
    }

    public static Message getByUserId(String userId) {
        Query query = new Query(entityKind);
        query.addFilter(userIdPropertyName, FilterOperator.EQUAL, userId);
        DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
        Entity entity = datastore.prepare(query).asSingleEntity();
        if (entity == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return new Message(entity);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: also line " if (parent == null || parent != null) {" is nonsense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from the slim possibility of a race in the static initializer, the problem with using a singleton parent is that there's a limit on the number of transactions per second that be done against a given parent. If you're using a singleton instance, you're building in a bottleneck.

You'll have much better luck using some distinguished entity as the parent of the entity group. Say, an entity representing the user who is getting the messages. That has the nice side-effect of doing away with the need for the static initializer.